# Accessing FacesContext from a thread

Tags: multithreading, jsf, facescontext

In my JSF app I need to display FacesMessage from another thread. Acording to docs it's not possible. But maybe there is some trick to do so? I can't see another way to do what I wan't to :(

Comment: I want to display a message that the thread did something (it is making some operations in the while(true) loop and if there is no more data in the database it could process it calls wait - that's the moment I want to display a message, later some other user action calls notify).

Comment: Is it possible to choose a certain JSF implementation/framework? Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve your problem with asynchronous background work with ICEfaces server side push.
Pleas take a look at http://auctionmonitor.icefaces.org/auctionMonitor/auctionMonitor.jsf for an example of the push technology.

Your background working thread could perform a "push", which will "notify" certain pages to update (partially) and display your message.

Comment: are you spamming the site? You provided identical answers here and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399517/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread/7401733#7401733

Comment: @Code Monkey: It's a duplicate question (which I flagged), so I duplicated my answer too.
May one of them survive.

Comment: It's not a duplicate per the exact duplicate guidelines.